# cURL vs __SoapClient for PHP Soap Application

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm having a recurring issue with PHP's inbuilt SOAP client where it returns the same error response regardless of the input paramaters.

**Is there an advantage to using the SOAP library built into PHP or a disadvantage to directly querying via cURL through GET?**

```
    $client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/wdsl"); 

    $params = array(
        'Username' => 'username',
        'Password' => 'pass',
        'EventName' => 'Test Event',
        'EventDate' => '2011-06-15T13:45:30',
        'Destination' => '447987654321',
        'Carrier' => '1',
        'PhoneType' => '13',
        'Originator' => 'ukflive',
        'MessageText' => 'Test',
        'LogoURL' => 'http://example.com/mail.gif',
        'BookingReference' => '123456',
        'Tickets' => '1',
        'CollectionValidFrom' => '2011-06-15T13:45:30',
        'CollectionValidTo' => '2011-06-15T18:45:30',
        'TemplatePath' => '',
        'PostBack' => 'http://example.com/'
    );

    $response = $client->__soapCall("SendManagedMobileTicket", $params); 

    print_r($response);
```

Comment: are you saying that you want more descriptive error reposnses, or that you haven't gotten it to work at all?  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SoapClient is an integrated, actively maintained part of PHP5.  cURL is the quick and dirty way to send HTTP data.  The smart long term decision is to stick with SoapClient and its methods.

You may also want to look into the response headers, as shown in the notes section of the __soapCall() documentation page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php#102387

Comment: Well, cURL isn't exactly doing things QUICK - the quick way would be `file_get_contents()`, and that is really dirty. cURL has the benefit of respecting secure default settings for SSL, but you are correct: Doing Soap with cURL or anything else that hasn't the WSDL/XML parsing implemented internally is cumbersome.

Comment: The PHP SOAP client is very inflexible and difficult to use for any use case that does something esoteric.  For example if you're required to wrap a document that uses multiple XML namespaces in a SOAP envelope you have no control over what the namespace alias will be (it will be ns1, ns2, ns3...).  SOAP - PHP Class mapping also doesn't work as well as it could.  Sometimes you might be better off just building your own XML and using cURL to make the actual call and just dealing with error cases yourself.